# Creating a Questionnaire in Android

Tags: android, android-widget, android-sqlite

Peace be on all of you!
I have to develop a questionnaire like small android app. There will be 10 questions with only 2 types of answers, i.e. either "Yes" or "No". When the user will answer all of the 10 questions, a report will be shown to user according to his answers.
Kindly tell me, how should I proceed? Do I need to use database (sqlite) or can work without it? and how should I start to develop this app?
I am new to Android.
Thank-you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are new to Android, than use a web approach: Show a html page 1-10  in a webView and link it each other and finally the 10th is linked to an url, where you will do a http POST / GET with your collected 10 params. Exactly as how would you do in a "standard' web development. Also you can use several app to wrapp into Android app: Appcelerator, Phonegap and so on.

Comment: Thank-you Matheszabi! It will be a kind of psychological test/questionnaire. As there are 10 question with 2 options for answers; there will be different combinations as user can choose different options for each question every time he fills questionnaire. Then how I will manage each type of report or result of test?

Comment: And I want to make it an expert module which can Learn as well, meaning if user choose some different combination which is not being handled in code, then system can handle that intelligently and learn this new combination. Kindly tell Is it possible to do so using WebView?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a class which is a screen: (Android Activity)

```
public class Help  extends Activity{

    private WebView webViewHelp;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.help);

        webViewHelp = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webViewHelp);

        webViewHelp.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/ui/help.html");
    }
}
```

you need the help.xml build and placed into /res/layout/ folder.

Also write the help.html and place it into: **/assets/ui** folder and not android_asset and at is not `file:///assets/ui/help.html`!

in this case you have the starting point set up, than go and load with html links the next next next ... until is done, than pust url.

Somewhat easyer if you are doing in android ui development, and not web-like, but that need a bit more experience

Comment: Dear Matheszabi! Thank-you for your time, but I'm sorry, I really don't understand what are you saying. I know this very thing that how to put questions and their options using radio buttons and all that, but what i don't know is that how to manage results and how to rate the user's test after evaluating his answers.

Comment: you have told you are beginner in android development, that is why I suggested the web approach, because everybody knows web ( just me not ), but if you don't know either how stuff works on web pages, than you should really consider paying a pizza and let cheap developers to do the job for you at freelancer.com. When you have the code, and something is working that is a bit easier to ask how to change it a bit. Now it is like "I don't know anything about flying but I want to make a simple airplane, please help"